# At which point in the universe history will inflation prevent galaxies feeding from intergalactic matter?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, cosmological-inflation, galaxies

It's my understanding that galaxies formed from accretion of intergalactic matter around supermassive black holes. As the universe expands the amount of matter entering a galaxy decreases, until at some point this process stops or becomes negligible.

At which point in the past or the future will matter accretion from the intergalactic medium cease? How is this point in time shifted by the filamentous organization of baryonic intergalactic matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although galaxies are moving apart from one another faster and faster, it is only at the largest scales where the average energy density of matter is smaller than the dark energy density. Clusters and superclusters of galaxies are unlikely to dissolve because they are more energy-dense than dark energy, and they will only become more dense as they collapse from their own self-gravity.